# modal gets closed and data is updated, but the screen appears dark

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I want the table to be updated after entering the data, without the page getting refreshed. The data gets updated but after clicking save/submit button, the page appears dark.

Ajax code goes here:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){

var url = $('#editform').attr('action');
     var data = $('#editform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method:'post',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/project/updateData",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
                            $('#editform')[0].reset();
            $('#editmodal').modal('hide');
            showproject();
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Data not inserted.');
    }
});
});
```

`function showproject(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/project/project_show",
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data:{
        show: 1
      },
      success: function(response){
          $('#editmodal').modal('hide');
        $('#userTable').html(response);
      }
    });
  }`

`showproject()` is a function to display the table which shows the updated data and redirects to controller, which in turn redirects to the same page where this ajax function is present.(is that the issue? if it so, how will i correct it?) 
How will i get the updated data without refreshing the page?

Comment: url should be something pointing to a controller function (as you use it could eventually work, but we don't know as you don't show); don't do redirect in controller, as you come back in ajax success. try to correct this and update your question with controller code

Comment: what is `modal('hide')`? a jquery plugin function?, what does your function `showproject()` do? Please read about [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: $(modalname).modal('hide') is to close/hide modal after submitting

Comment: please update your code with controller code and also handle error in showproject() function